# JQM is messing up look and function of select combobox

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have been working on this for a few days now. And I do not get why my select is looking and acting so strange.

[image: dropdown select]

I have tried to disable all JS and CSS one at a time. 
I have tried tot leave only the bear minimum.
I disabled my custom style css and the JQ plugins I use. 
I downloaded fresh Jquery Mobile files and included these.
I have switched my select for a standard select from the JQM demo page. 
It all made no difference to how the select looked and behaved. 
The select (my or JQM Demo) gets a display none and JQM makes it in to another (shoot be better looking) select.

Also when I select an option it stays open and is very wide as you see in the image. The only way to get it to look somewhat normal is to refresh the page.

If I remove this from the page in DevTools console (FF of Chrome) and I change the original select to `display: normal;` I get the select back with no enhancements.

I want the select to look as on the JQM demo page.

Comment: I am not allowed to place images yet here. So thats why the link looks like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, your problem is that jQuery Mobile is styling select box and you want it to stay unstyled?

There are several approaches to this:

1. Add **data-enhance=”false”** attribute to all elements you do not want jQuery Mobile to style. You can use it on one element or on parent elements and jQuery Mobile will prevent markup enhancement on all child elements also.
2. If you want to do this on only one element only use this attribute: **data-role=”none”**

[Here](https://www.gajotres.net/how-to-remove-jquery-mobile-styling/) you can find working examples.

Comment: data-role=”none” that did the trick. Thanks a lot @Gajotres !